# Limit of a two dimensional function $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^4+y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I've got to find out, if there is a continous function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^4+y^4}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0.0)$ ?

My answer is: As the function is a composition of continous functions, it is continous for $(x,y) \neq (0.0)$.

Investigating for $(0,0)$, I tranformed it with $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ to polar coordinates and get:

$\frac{r^2 \cos\phi \sin\phi(r^2(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)}{r^4(\cos^4\phi+\sin^4)\phi)}=\frac{\cos\phi \sin\phi (\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)}{\cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi}$, which is not continous for $r \rightarrow0$ and also not continuous for $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0).$ Am I right with these arguments or am I missing some important point?

Comment: You have to investigate differenet paths towards the origin to show that the function is not continuous there. Take for example $x\rightarrow y,y\rightarrow0$ and compare it with $x\rightarrow 2y,y\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. In general, when the order of the numerator and the denominator are equal, as it is in your example, it is useful to check the behaviour of the function along lines of the form $y=kx$ for various values of $k$. For example, if you take $y=2x$ you get for $x\neq 0$,
$$f(x,2x)=\frac{2x^2(x^2-4x^2)}{x^4+16x^4}=-\frac{6}{17}$$
but if you take $y=x$ you get $f(x,x)=0$, so the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist, as it has different limits along different lines approaching zero.

Comment: typo : $x^2-4x^2$

Comment: thank you, corrected.